# Does HTTPS prevent a valid user from tampering with the payload?

Tags: security

We have 2 web applications, both secured using HTTPS (server-side certificates only) and a single sign-on authentication system. In App1, a user will click a link which then needs to “drill down” into a page in App2. They share the same domain and SSL certificate, but are physically not the same app. When App1 forwards or redirects the request to App2, it includes an authentication token in the request so App2 can verify the user’s identity.

App1 knows what information the user is authorized to see, call it a list of accounts; App2 does not have access to this information (at least not at this time). It has been proposed that App1 may pass the list of authorized accounts to App2 as well, in the request.

My question is whether HTTPS protects the payload and guarantees that it was generated only by the App1/App2 servers? More specifically, my concern is whether a valid user, with a valid authentication token, might be able to build his own form with additional accounts and submit it as a valid HTTPS POST request to the App2 server and thereby gain access to unauthorized accounts?

Comment: So you already know that sending crafted HTTP requests allows to gain access to unauthorized accounts?

Comment: Oh, and have you already read the [Wikipedia article on *HTTPS*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure), especially the second paragraph? It explains in detail what HTTPS provides.

Comment: My interpretation of this article and ones like it, is that HTTPS prevents tampering of the payload by any third party. My question is about tampering by the client himself, and not by a third party. But I would guess you are suggesting it's the same thing?

Comment: Yes, HTTPS prevents tampering by third party during transmission only; the other two parties can still tamper.

Answer (score 4):

No, HTTPS alone does not provide you with the security you're looking for.  For an indication of how others have tackled the problem you're facing, take a look at this link:

[SSO with SAML](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73/helpdata/en/47/feefe5ed7045458d2886a68bbb46f1/frameset.htm)

It is about accomplishing SSO with the SAML protocol.  In general if security is a serious concern of yours, you'll want to use a peer-reviewed solution (like SAML) instead of a DIY approach to single sign-on.  You don't need to use SAML, but you should try to use an existing SSO solution available for your environment.

In order to "guarantee it was generated by the App1/App2 servers" -- you *could* digitally sign the payload.  This would prevent tampering but may not prevent [replay attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack) -- SSL would help some with that as the transmission would be encrypted but replay attacks would still be possible (via perhaps a [man in the middle attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Man-in-the-middle_attack))

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally down voted this answer when scrolling, think I've fixed it, but not sure.

Comment: Regarding this:

  In order to "guarantee it was generated by the App1/App2 servers" -- you could digitally sign the payload. 

Isn't this what HTTPS does for me out of the box?

Comment: Yes and no.  It does guarantee to the client that the response came from the App1 server, but it does not guarantee to the App2 server that the subsequent request from the client was generated by the App1 server.

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS provides a secure communication channel.
But you could have a secure communication with the devil himself
:-)